# List multidimensional array and display few in C language

Tags: c

Can someone help me answer what's wrong with my code? I'm actually working on a flow that an array of 5 characters will display first 3 array first then so on and so forth until reaching the last file. Meanwhile, this code of mine replaces the list[0] by list[2]. And I don't know why.

Thank you in advanced.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main() 
{
int i, ch, j;
static int v;
const char list[5][15] = {"ANNYEONG","SARANGHAE","KOMAWO","BOGOSHIPDA", "MIANHAE"};
char display[2][15];

do
{
    do
    {
        for (i=0; i<=4; i++)
        {
            printf ("\nlist[%d]: |%s|\n",i,list[i]);
        }
        printf ("\nMAIN MENU");
        printf ("\n1.Display");
        printf ("\n2.Display (Reverse the Execution)");
        printf ("\n3.Exit (End the Execution)");
        printf ("\nEnter Your Choice: ");
        scanf  ("%d", &ch);
        if (ch<1 || ch>3)
        {
            printf ("\nInvalid Choice, Please try again");
        }
    }
    while (ch<1 || ch>3);

    switch (ch)
    {
        case 1:
            printf ("\nValue of v: %d\n",v);
            if(v <= 2) {
                for (i=0; i<3; i++)
                {
                    memset(display[i], 0, sizeof(display[i]));
                    strcpy(display[i], list[i+v]);
                    printf ("\n--------\n| %s |\n--------",display[i]);
                }
                v++;
            }
            printf ("\nValue of v: %d\n",v);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf ("\nValue of v: %d\n",v);
            v--;

            if(v >= 0) {

                printf ("\nValue of v: %d\n",v);
                for (i=0; i<=2; i++)
                {
                    memset(display[i], 0, sizeof(display[i]));
                    strcpy(display[i], list[i+v]);
                    printf ("\n--------\n| %s |\n--------",display[i]);
                }
            } else {
                v = 0;
            }
            printf ("\nValue of v: %d\n",v);
            break;
        default:
            printf ("\nEND OF EXECUTION");
   }
}
while (ch != 3);
getch();
}
```

Comment: If I were you I'd paste the errors (using the code button for that as well). What exactly went wrong? That is just a general guideline.

Answer (score 1):

I'm out of my mind. I overlooked the array of display.

```
char display[2][15];
```

Hahaha. Tha should be:

```
char display[3][15];
```

Solving my own problem. :D